# configuring phpunit on xampp windows

Tags: php, phpunit

i'm trying to configure phpunit but its not working ! -its my first time with phpunit-

i had it installed via pear, on windows 7 -xampp server- and its working fine, problem is that `phpunit.xml` file just doesnt seem to be working wt so ever.

[image]

as you can see phpunit.xml located at the root of my project is found but just cann't find my tests :(. if i direct it manualy the tests run just fine. this is my phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./test/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

My project is a CodeIgniter framework located on E:\xampp\htdocs\ehit
Directory structure
-ehit
--application
--system
--test

so what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using CIUnit in codeigniter, try adding path to bootstrap like:

```
<phpunit 
    colors="true" 
    bootstrap="/application/third_party/CIUnit/bootstrap_phpunit.php">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```